# Mapping a different icon depending on property value in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am now working with Angular and TypeScript which I'm new to. I previously raised a similar question for ReactJS a while back - I basically want the same outcome to this https://codesandbox.io/s/ojz2lzz03z

I want to map a specific icon to my component.html

```
<fa-icon icon="{{icon}}"></fa-icon>
```

depending on the output of the json property. Mapping to something like this:

```
const icon = 
  { "east": "coffee",
    "north": "user-secret",
    "south": "sort-up",
  };
```

My component.ts looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-timeline-entry',
  templateUrl: './timeline-entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timeline-entry.component.css']
})
export class TimelineEntryComponent {
  @Input() timeEntryHeader: string;
  @Input() timeEntryContent: string;
  @Input() timeEntryPlace: string;
  @Input() timeEntryLocation: string; //this is where north/east/south come from
}
```

I have created a stackblitz to mimic my setup: https://timeline-angular-7-6hx9db.stackblitz.io

Comment: `icon[timeEntryLocation]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you edit my stackblitz to demonstrate please?

Comment: If you have a failing attempt, please put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. However, I was not sure how to write in  a ts file. With react all logic is on the same file. Its actually easier with Angular with the below answer but was not sure how to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the map globally in the component so you can access it in your HTML.

```
public iconMap = { 
  east: "coffee",
  north: "user-secret",
  south: "sort-up"
};
```

Then if the input `timeEntryLocation` was equal to east, north or south you could access the map with it to access the icon that is going to be used.

This would look like this.

```
<fa-icon icon="{{ iconMap[timeEntryLocation] }}"></fa-icon>
```

This should give you the Icon you wanted.